# windows phone developer power tools 8.1 connectivity error 0x80070057

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

[image]

when I try to connect WP developer tools 8.1. I keep getting above errors.

Any pointer will be highly appreciated.

Thanks and Regards
Nishant Rana

Answer (score 5):

Wait for the phone to receive an update :)
Then everything should work like a charm.

Comment: Thank you very much, the update has just arrived... why this is not explained in the help page of this tools??

Comment: Who knows:/ I must admit Microsoft has poor support when we talk about Windows Phone :/